# How to convert fields in an array into individual objects

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the following values from my reactive form in an array:

```
ADVERSE_POSESSION: ""
PRIMARY_RESIDENCE: "Yes"
SUBJECT_TO_TENANCY: "Tenancy"
```

How do I iterate over these fields so that each field is it's own object in an array?

My desired out put is:

```
{
    "fieldId": "ADVERSE_POSESSION",
    "value": ""
},
{
    "fieldId": "PRIMARY_RESIDENCE",
    "value": "Yes"
},
{
    "fieldId": "SUBJECT_TO_TENANCY",
    "value": "Tenancy"
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: I've tried asking this question on SO, and thankfully got just the answer I wanted.

Comment: @RobbieMills mine? glad I could help. I don't understand all the downvotes, a good comment like the top one here would have been good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remap it. Here's an example.

```js
const formValue = {
  ADVERSE_POSESSION: "",
  PRIMARY_RESIDENCE: "Yes",
  SUBJECT_TO_TENANCY: "Tenancy",
}; // Likely this.formGroup.getRawValue()

const array = Object.keys(formValue).map(key => ({ fieldId: key, value: formValue[key] }));
console.log(array);
```